# Drop Downs in new ROW

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Data Validation in one Column, When new ROWs are added to the bottom it doesn't copy the Data Validation and just gives me blank cells.

Is there a script I can use so every time new ROWs are added it contains the Data Validation Drop Down? I've searched and searched, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option that at least can give you some ideas, is to use the trigger `onEdit` - [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), as follows:

```js
function setDataValidation(cell) {
  var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
             .newDataValidation()
             .requireValueInList(array, true)
             .setAllowInvalid(false)
             .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range, s = range.getSheet();
  if(e.value && s.getName() === 'Sheet1') {
    setDataValidation(s.getRange(range.getRow(), 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you try using onChange rather than onEdit.? Adding a new row is not triggered by onEdit.

Comment: @Sergeinsas: Yes, it was the first choice, but get the row to insert data validation, in onChange, not easy.

Comment: Let me check this out. Thank you

Comment: Sorry Im a total nube with this app script. I copy and pasted into my manager. Ran the DV went for the on edit but got a range error, is there something I need to change in this to match my spreadsheet?

Comment: @user2970972: I can not reproduce the problem. What other information can you give me about the problem?

Comment: Line 12 range undefined, Line 8 setdatavalidation undefined Thank you for helping! More over > .cell undefined line 8 ; onEdit- Line 12 e s and range undefined.

Comment: @user2970972: Are you trying to run the code from the editor? To see the functionality of the code, copy and paste the code in the editor, save and go to the sheet `Sheet1`. Write something in cell `A1`, press enter, you should see the data validation in cell `B2`.

Comment: Ok, so im wondering now, Is there to automatically put the DV if there is a true value in A. Right now this is a shipping sheet, like a pick list, So there are many lines of backorder items. So if this code recognized that there was a value in cell A it would populate all the row with the Data Validation. Follow? And thanks again for helping me!

Comment: I think I owe you a six pack